# Chromedriver timing out, was working before

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am working with Selenium/python combo and I have a bunch of scripts which were working perfectly. I then stopped using them for a month and now I get time out errors. I have tried a couple of solutions posted on-line but nothing seems to work.

This is the set-up:

```
selenium     3.141.0
chrome       86.0.4240.75
chromedriver 86.0.4240.22
```

and the errors I get are:

```
[11-28-2020 23:33:28.070][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\googlechrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --log-level=0 --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\VB\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir29140_1635643004" data:,
[11-28-2020 23:33:28.589][INFO]: resolved localhost to ["::1","127.0.0.1"]
[11-28-2020 23:33:32.588][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[11-28-2020 23:33:32.588][INFO]: resolved localhost to ["::1","127.0.0.1"]
[11-28-2020 23:33:40.598][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[11-28-2020 23:33:40.598][INFO]: resolved localhost to ["::1","127.0.0.1"]
[11-28-2020 23:33:56.604][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, giving up.
[11-28-2020 23:33:56.606][INFO]: resolved localhost to ["::1","127.0.0.1"]
[11-28-2020 23:34:00.615][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[11-28-2020 23:34:00.615][INFO]: resolved localhost to ["::1","127.0.0.1"]
[11-28-2020 23:34:08.627][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[11-28-2020 23:34:08.627][INFO]: resolved localhost to ["::1","127.0.0.1"]
[11-28-2020 23:34:24.634][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, giving up.
[11-28-2020 23:34:24.659][INFO]: [fcdf702ffc801fde76b9fd0d0815b3df] RESPONSE InitSession ERROR session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)
```

This is my chrome/chromedriver config:

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\googlechrome.exe'
chrome_driver_binary = "C:\Program Files\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, options=options, service_args=["--disable-gpu","--readable-timestamp","--log-path=C://DOCS//python//" + className + "_" + memberName + "_TEST_chromedriver.log"])
```

and I changed hosts to add:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/DOCS/python/gym/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, options=options, service_args=["--disable-gpu","--readable-timestamp","--log-path=C://DOCS//python//" + className + "_" + memberName + "_TEST_chromedriver.log"])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)
```

failure point:

```
LINE 18: options = Options()
LINE 19: options.binary_location = 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\googlechrome.exe'
LINE 20: chrome_driver_binary = "C:\Program Files\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
LINE 21: driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, options=options, service_args=["--disable-gpu","--readable-timestamp","--log-path=C://DOCS//python//" + className + "_" + memberName + "_TEST_chromedriver.log"])
```

I tried upgrading chrome and chromedriver to v87 but that gave same error so I reverted to 86. As I said it was working fine before. I can't think of anything that has changed particularly.

Any ideas of what to try would be great.

Comment: All I am seeing are INFO and WARNING messages. No errors. Is your script working? Can you add the error message and stack trace to your question?

Comment: Please add this to your question. It is too hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Details added to original post.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just to add, when I run it manually from pyCharm it starts an instance of Chrome but then does nothing until it fails.